# Writting/reading an integer array into a file on android

Tags: java, android, file-io, integer

i'm very new to the input/output topic, and i'm stuck on one thing.

What i want is to save on the internal storage an int array with many values useful for my app(such as the highscore, coins grabbed in-game, etc).
I'm wondering if this is the best way to save this kind of data, becuase i can't find any information on the internet for doing this.

This is my actual code:

```
int[] numbers = new int[5];
        for(int i = 0; i>5; i++){
            numbers[i] = i*2 +1;
        }
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(openFileOutput("data.dat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)));
        for(int i = 0; i>5; i++){
            dos.writeInt(numbers[i]);
            dos.flush();
        }
```

When i run the app i can find the data.dat file on the internal storage of my phone, but its seems to be empty as its 0.00 bytes weight.

Please, what would be the best way to storage several integers (such as those ones) and how can i make to read after that?

From now, Thanks :)

Comment: Do you close the output stream after you're done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a closer look at your loop's exit condition: it doesn't execute even once since 0 is less than 5:

```
for(int i = 0; i>5; i++){ ... }
```

You probably meant to write:

```
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){ .... }
```

Comment: (facepalm) sorry, i didn't realise that, forgive me for this stupid thing.. I changed it and its works, now i have the data on the file, but what should i do to read every single int in the array?Thx for help

Answer (score 0):

A SQLite database may be more appropriate for this.  You can look up tons of tutorials on [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) for help.

Also, at first glance, you should be closing your `dos` object at the end.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is SharedPreferences. Take a look at this [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

There are some other storage methods in android. You can find different methods [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)